# Change data view in excel

Tags: excel

I want to change the way data is shown on an excel sheet. Here are the images that describe how it looks currently

[image]

But I want to include one row per B code columns something like this:

[image]

Tried transposing etc but it did not work

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub run()


    Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ServiceName As String, Route As String, B_Code As String
    Dim sDate As Date
    Dim Code_Value As Double

    'Change sheet if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            ServiceName = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            sDate = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            Route = .Cells(i, 3).Value

            For j = 4 To LastColumn

                B_Code = .Cells(1, j).Value
                Code_Value = .Cells(i, j).Value

                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

                    LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                    .Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 1).Value = sDate
                    .Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 2).Value = ServiceName
                    .Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 3).Value = Route
                    .Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 4).Value = B_Code
                    .Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 5).Value = Code_Value

                End With

            Next j

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

The results as paste in Sheet2

Comment: Thanks @Error 1004 for your answer. Looks like this is a vb code. Is it possible for us to achieve this using any tools within excel?

Comment: i can not think anything which may help you achieving the result

Comment: Ok thanks! Thank you for your help once again :) @Error 1004